# Skopeo tool for docker images - Retagging

Tags: docker, docker-registry, skopeo

I am downloading a docker image using Skopeo tool on a linux machine - Works successfully

```
skopeo copy --src-creds uname:pwd docker://url/image:tag dir:/home/image
```

I am trying to change the tag of this image. Currently the image tag is "latest" which needs to be changed as "new"

Is there any way using **skopeo tool** we can re-tag this image then upload to registry with a new tag.

Please Note: Docker is not allowed to be installed on linux machine as it needs root user which is unauthorized for our project.

I am trying the below sequence of activities

1. Download an image from repository with tag "latest"- working
2. Change the tag of the image to "new" and upload back to repository - working
3. Download the image with new tag "new" - Fails with error.

PFB the commands in sequential order

```
skopeo copy --src-creds name:pwd docker://url/alpine:latest dir:/home/alpine

skopeo copy --dest-creds uname:pwd dir:/home/alpine docker://url/alpine:new 

skopeo copy --src-creds uname:pwd docker://url/alpine:new dir:./alpinenew
**FATA[0004] Error initializing source docker://url/alpine:new: Error reading manifest new in url/alpine: manifest unknown: manifest unknown**
```

How to fix this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to "retag" the image. You set the tag when you upload the image to a remote repository. For example, to upload the image as `myusername/myimagename:sometag`, I could run:

```
skopeo copy dir:/home/image docker://myusername/myimagename:sometag
```

To illustrate this, I can download the `alpine` image like this:

```
skopeo copy docker://alpine dir:./alpine
```

And then upload this into my own namespace with a different name and tag like this:

```
skopeo copy dir:alpine docker://larsks/alpinetest:foo
```

That [seems to work just fine](https://hub.docker.com/repository/docker/larsks/alpinetest/tags).

I can then download the new image to verify that it worked:

```
$ skopeo copy docker://larsks/alpinetest:foo dir:./alpinetest
Getting image source signatures
Copying blob e6b0cf9c0882 done
Copying config cc0abc535e done
Writing manifest to image destination
Storing signatures
```

---

This works just fine using the same image name in both locations:

```
skopeo copy docker://larsks/alpinetest:foo dir:./alpinetest
skopeo copy dir:./alpinetest docker://larsks/alpinetest:bar
```

This [adds a new tag to the image](https://hub.docker.com/repository/docker/larsks/alpinetest/tags).

Comment: Added my question below

Comment: But here after downloading along with new tag name, image name is also changed. But we need to use the same image name with new tag

Comment: Just like we need to change the tag name (to differentate version) but the image name should be retained the same

Comment: So then don't change the imagename. I've added an additional example that just adds a new tag.

Comment: Getting this error -> -bash-4.2$ skopeo copy docker://url/alpinetest:foo dir:./alpinetest
FATA[0004] Error initializing source docker://url/alpinetest:foo: Error reading manifest foo in url/alpinetest: manifest unknown: manifest unknown

Comment: If I change the image name or tag name I am getting error as below -> FATA[0004] Error initializing source docker://url/alpinetest:foo: Error reading manifest foo in url/alpinetest: manifest unknown: manifest unknown

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce those errors, even using a local registry. Could you update your question to show the exact sequence of commands that you're running? Putting it in the question is easier because you can properly format things...